# Getting handshake_failure when pulling dependencies from Maven on EC2 Instance

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, maven-3

This is only happens to 3rd party Maven repository for ElasticSearch on EC2 instance. It's working fine locally.

https://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases

Is it a configuration issue?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project system-s: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project com.7leaf:system-s:jar:0.0.1: Failed to collect 
dependencies at org.elasticsearch.plugin:shield:jar:2.4.1: Failed to read 
artifact descriptor for org.elasticsearch.plugin:shield:jar:2.4.1: Could not 
transfer artifact org.elasticsearch.plugin:shield:pom:2.4.1 from/to es-repo 
(https://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases): Received fatal alert: 
handshake_failure -> [Help 1]
```

This is the Maven and Java version on the server.

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/share/apache-maven
Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.24.amzn1.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.23-31.51.amzn1.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After trying out a few things, I found out that the issue is SSL and for this case, I'm able to switch to use non-SSL endpoint instead to solve the issue.

Switch to use

http://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases

instead of

https://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases

Comment: HTTPS is used for a reason. This should not be an acceptable fix to the problem.